# Открытие нового окна после закрытия главного pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt5

Нужно обработать ошибку. Как после закрытия главного окна в случае выполнения условия открыть новое окно? Также можно бы было сразу открыть новое окно, а потом завершить старое, но у меня не получилось (QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit() и app.quit() закрывает всё)

Answer (score 1):

Вот так сделайте - проще будет.

```
self.Error.setModal(True)
self.Error.show()
```

Comment: попробуйте более развёрнуты ответы писать. Поясните в чём именно была проблема в вопросе (с чем связано *"у меня не получилось"*) и как именно приведённый в ответе  код  эту проблему решает.